# How does deny deletion permission work in file sharing

Tags: permissions, file-sharing

We are sharing folders from a computer over a LAN network. I want users to be able to read and update those files but they should not be able to delete those files. The folder is shared with everyone.

I goto `Properties->security`. then click `everyone` and click on `advanced`.

There I select `everyone`, and then edit, then I open the `advanced sharing permissions`.[image]

After doing this, it does not allow making changes to the files inside the folders.

I have Windows 7.

Comment: [Share and NTFS Permissions on a File Server on Technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754178(v=ws.11).aspx) might be relevant. As for your question, what kind of files edited with what kind of software? There programs that tend to update a file by deleting it and recreating it.

Comment: There are database file (.db) and word, excel files. The db files can be edited but the word files and excel files donot allow saving after editing

Answer (score 0):

This happens because of how Microsoft Office documents are opened for editing. Other programs may behave similarly, but I'll refer strictly to Office files since there is documentation available that explains this behavior.

When you open an Office document, the application creates a hidden temporary file in the same folder. As you work in the document, your modifications are written to this file (as an aside, this is how it's possible for Auto Save to work).

When you *Save* the document, the original document is deleted, then the temp file is renamed to that of the original. Because your users don't have permission to delete files, the operation fails.

Here's an overview of the process as detailed in [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/211632/description-of-how-word-creates-temporary-files) Microsoft Word support article:

```
Create temp file                     Create ~wrdxxxx.tmp
Write temp file                      Save example data to ~wrdxxxx.tmp
Delete original file                 Delete EXAMPLE.DOC
Move temp to target name             Move ~wrdxxxx.tmp to Example.doc
```

According to the same article:

> Word gains significant performance speed by placing the temporary file in the same directory as the saved file.....The location where Word creates the temporary files is hardcoded information and cannot be edited. Therefore, it is important that NTFS permissions for the user are set accordingly.

I imagine this is the same for all Office desktop applications.  A complete list of NTFS permission required for Word (specifically) can be found [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/277867/windows-ntfs-permissions-are-required-when-you-run-word-on-any-ntfs-pa). NTFS Delete is one of them.

*See [original answer](https://serverfault.com/a/875106/205065) on Server Fault.*